# Calculate mean for uneven weighting in matlab

Tags: matlab, mean

I want to calculate the mean of a field of tracers in Matlab, but the cells that make up the field are a different size. For example, my tracer field is:

```
T = 
 1 3 5 8
 2 1 4 3
 2 1 9 1
 20 8 3 1
```

And I have 2 more fields, `dx` and `dy` which describe the size of the cells that make up `T`.

```
dx =
 1 1 2 3
 1 1 2 3
 1 1 2 3
 1 1 2 3
```

and

```
dy = 
 3 3 3 3
 3 3 3 3
 2 2 2 2
 1 1 1 1
```

So, intuitively, `dx` and `dy` tell me that the bottom left hand corner of the tracer field `T` should have the smallest contribution to a calculate of the mean of `T`, while the top right hand corner should have the greatest contribution.

I initially tried `mean(mean(T))`, but this obviously overweights the importance of the bottom left corner of `T`, etc. After a bit of investigation I figured I'd be thorough and calculate the mean manually, and including weightings, using something like this:

```
T_mean_i = sum(T*dx)./sum(dx)
```

And similar for `dy`, the cell width in the y-direction. However, I'm not sure how to implement this.

Edit: Here is some more detail for my question.

My grid is 260*380 cells, so `size(dy) = size(dx) = 260-by-380`. The tracer field is calculated by dividing a surface flux field, say `sflux` by a similarly sized salinity field, `salt`. So, `size(sflux) = size(salt) = 260-by-380-by-1000`, where the time dimension has length `1000`.

I want to find the mean of `sflux(:,:)./salt(:,:,ii)` **including** the weighting of the cell width fields, `dx` and `dy`, at each timestep `ii`. (I won't use a for-loop to do this, don't worry!!)

Am I on the right track with what I'm doing? Or am I think about this wrong? Please feel free to ask for clarification.

Cheers!

Comment: the wieght of each element: is it the **product** of `dx` and `dy` at the respective location, or the **sum** ?

Comment: Well, `dy.*dy` is the area of each cell. So, as far as I figure it, the area of each cell determines the weighting that should be given for the average. My only concern is that the result is *normalised* correctly...

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answers... I had shied away from using `(:)` as the field is actually 3-d (with the third dim. representing time). So, I want to calculate means at each time step. Using `(:)` will mean over all time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mean` and `sum` operate along a single dimension. To apply them on an entire matrix, convert the data to a column vector first using the [colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) (`:`), for example:

```
w = dx .* dy;
sum(w(:))
```

To obtain the desired mean for each layer in the 3-D array, you could do something like:

```
T = sflux ./ salt; %// Tracer field
w = dx .* dy;      %// Weights
T_mean = sum(reshape(bsxfun(@times, T, w), [], size(T, 3))) / sum(w(:));
```

This produces an array `T_mean` with elements corresponding to the mean values at each time step.

Explanation: `bsxfun(@times, T, w)` multiples each layer element-wise by the weights. The resulting weighted 3-D array is reshaped into a 2-D array, so that each column is converted into a different column (similar to the colon operator), and then everything is normalized by the sum of the weights.

Comment: Thanks for the help @EitanT! I have a query about this technique. `SomeMatrix = bsxfun(@times,T,w)` is reshaped to be a 2D matrix, in this case, to have a size of `260*380-by-1000`. How can I be sure that the elements of each row (i.e. elements from the 260*380) will have originated from `SomeMatrix(:,:,1)`? In other words, when `SomeMatrix` is reshaped, how do I know that **no** elements from a later timestep are introduced earlier on in the reshaped matrix?

Comment: @David_G `reshape` (as many MATLAB built-in functions) operates along the columns first, then the rows, then the 3rd dimension, and so on...  So if the number of elements in each layer of the original matrix equals to the length of each column in the new matrix, it will be guaranteed that no elements from one layer end up in another column. Try and see for yourself: `A = reshape(1:12, [2 2 3]); B = reshape(A, [], 3);`

Comment: WOW. On 2 accounts... (1) Thanks for the demo - I was never truly convinced that `reshape` was doing what I wanted... before now! (2) I just implemented your recommendation (`bsxfun`), and what was before taking me 7-8 hours on a facility with 96GB of RAM, has now nearly completed in 10-15 mins. Mind Blown!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by

```
sum(T(:).*dx(:).*dy(:))./( sum(dx(:).*dy(:) )
```

Note that you should use here the **element**-wise product `.*` and not the matrix product `*`.